# More Test cases in Unit or SIT?

Tags: testing

I had below question in one of the exam.

During software application testing, In which of these testing one would see more test scenarios written,Unit or SIT?

Answer (score 0):

Unit test cases should be written by developers. Testers test the functional aspect of software. SIT will make sure that application is working fine. SIT is the answer.

Comment: If defects found in initial stage then they would cost you less to fix. So in that case probably Unit could also have more TC's that SIT. More are the TC's, more scenarios tested. Any justification please.